How to get rid of the error " No AppCheckProvider installed" in VS code
I am making an application and I have created the registration and login part. The registration part was working and sending the data to firebase, but after I created the login part it stopped working and when I registered/logged in I got this error. How do I make it disappear? I haven't added anything related to appcheck and I don't want to use it either.

W/System  (31909): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(31909): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.

